# Need Help Making Methods work Together

Tags: java, arrays

This program is supposed to take the amount of hours to charge a phone from a user and take the time that the user wants to charge their phone (index 0-23), and return the cost depending on what rateTable says. The problem i'm having is with the getChargeStartTime method, which takes the number of hours the user wants to charge their phone and finds the best time to start charging for the lowest cost. I've been able to get every method working individually but its proven to be a challenge to make them work in unison.

Heres an example of what the program is supposed to do (going to be using the values of rateTable below):
    User Inputs that they want to charge their phone for 3 hours starting at index 4. getCharging cost would then go to index 4 and add up the next 3 values, returning 88. the method getChargeStartTime would then take the amount of hours and loop through the array on its own to find the cheapest time to charge. So in this example it would eventually find index 21-23 which returns 40.

```
private int[] rateTable = 
    {5,10,26,35,23,30,35,40,45,66,58,50,75,
        65,30,55,44,45,32,25,31,15,10,15};

private int getChargingCost(int startHour, int chargeTime){
    int usercost = 0;
    String start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "At what hour do you want to start charging your phone? (0-23)");
    startHour = Integer.parseInt(start);


    String time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             "How many hours do you want to charge your phone?");
    chargeTime = Integer.parseInt(time);


    for (int hour = 0; hour < chargeTime; hour++){
        usercost += rateTable[(startHour + hour) % 24];
    }
    return usercost;

}

public int getChargeStartTime(int chargeTime) {
    int bestStartHour = 0;
    int minCost = getChargingCost(0, chargeTime);
    for( int hour = 1 ; hour <24 ; hour++){
        int cost = getChargingCost(hour, chargeTime);
        if(cost < minCost){
            bestStartHour = hour;
            minCost = cost;
        }
            return bestStartHour;
    }
return chargeTime;
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    BatteryCharger obj = new BatteryCharger();
    obj.getChargingCost(startHour, chargeTime);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
            "Charging your phone for " + chargeTime + 
            " hours will cost $" + usercost + ", but if you start at hour " + bestStartHour + " it will only cost you " + cost );

            }
        }
```

Comment: `obj.getChargingCost(startHour, chargeTime)`... You have not assigned `startHour` or `chargeTime`...?

Answer (score 0):

In the code as you have written `cost < minCost` is wrong. You want to set `max cost` there and then  loop through so that the value will end as the lowest cost.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parameters here. You assign the values of `startHour` and `chargeTime` within the method, therefore ignoring the values you passed in.

Try this instead.

```
private int getChargingCost(){

    String start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "At what hour do you want to start charging your phone? (0-23)");
    int startHour = Integer.parseInt(start);


    String time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             "How many hours do you want to charge your phone?");
    int chargeTime = Integer.parseInt(time);

    ...
}
```

And use the return value of that method, probably

```
BatteryCharger obj = new BatteryCharger();
int cost = obj.getChargingCost();
```

Also, read up on what "variable scope" means.

`chargeTime`, `usercost`, and `bestStartHour` cannot be accessed from the main method.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
        "Charging your phone for " + chargeTime + 
        " hours will cost $" + usercost + ", but if you start at hour " + bestStartHour + " it will only cost you " + cost );

        }
```